# laravel how to delete file in storage when we delete data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have some problem to delete file when some value deleted.

This is my delete function:

```
public function delete($id, Adopsi $adopsi)
{
    Storage::delete('post/adopsi/' . $adopsi->image_post_adps);
    $data = Adopsi::where('id', $id)->delete();

    if ($data) {
        return redirect()->route('adopsi.index')->with('success', 'Data telah dihapus');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('adopsi.index')->with('error', 'Data gagal dihapus');

    }
}
```

This is how I store my image before:

```
$imageSize = $request->file('image_post_adps')->getSize();
$imageName = $request->file('image_post_adps')->getClientOriginalName();
$request->file('image_post_adps')->storeAs('public/post/adopsi', $imageName);
```

directory folder where is use to save:
`storage/app/public/post/adopsi/.....` (there's my file),

I've used `Storage::delete()` and `unlink()` but it still isn't working.

Comment: have you check your webserver has right access to the file and directory?

Comment: how do i check my webserver access?

Comment: Please can you show the `Route` you have for this method.

Comment: Route::get('adopsi/delete/{id}', [AdopsiController::class,'delete'])->name('adopsi.delete');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are stored at 'public' disk path. But disk is not specified in delete()

Try

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete('post/adopsi/' . $adopsi->image_post_adps);
```

Comment: is it 'public' disk path declared by laravel in filesystem.php?
i mean, could be this your mean :
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Comment: yes, your file location is `storage/app/public/`. So you have to either use complete path like `Storage::delete('app/public/post/adopsi/'` or specify disk.

Comment: i've used your suggestion but it's same

Comment: please make sure that `$adopsi->image_post_adps` has the image filename.

Comment: image name only or with extension? bcs in db, it's was stored with filename.extension like cat.jpg

Comment: image name with extension.

Comment: thank's bro, been modify my code & add your solution to my code and it's work, thank you. have a great day and may god bless you

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the file exists by building the path:

First of all, add the File Facade at the top of the controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

You can use `public_path()` & `storage_path()`:

```
$path = public_path('../storage/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/YOUR_FILE_NAME');
if (!File::exists($path)) {
    File::delete(public_path('storage/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/YOUR_FILE_NAME'));
}

$path = storage_path().'/app/public/post/adopsi/'.$db->image;
if(File::exists($path)) {
    File::delete($path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me

```
$destinationPath = storage_path() . '/app/public/images/products';

File::delete($destinationPath . '/' . $product->id . '.' . $fileExtension);
```